# Asp.net table display using grid view and deleting one row in the website

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, database

I am displaying a table in a grid view in a asp.net webpage. I want the user to select one row in the website and delete it. How can I do that. I have a delete button in the same page, where I will do code behind to drop the row in the database. But my problem is how can user select one row in the table .

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="style29">
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Send Message to Group">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
             PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("GroupName", "SendMessage.aspx?GroupName={0}") %>' 
             Text='Send Message'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Is it possible to do without a check box? Or can I add a delete image to the table in a separate column and on clicking the button the row will be deleted.

Comment: please show us what you have done and where you are stuck at.

Comment: do you have delete button outside the gridview if so then put a template field of checkboxes and delete the checked records on button_click event

Comment: without any code/Markup we can just assume the situation and try which will not a good way to get your question answered

Comment: is it possible to do without a check box?

Comment: yes for sure you can do it without checkbox also but i was suggesting because that's an easy and user friendly way of doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"/>
```

on your gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ICallbackEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx) to trigger an action on the server.

> But my problem is how can user select one row in the table .

this code adds a Select button:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
```

Now your problem is only to get the server to execute some piece of code, do that using ICallbackEventHandler or Ajax.